# Realm case insensitive search syntax

Tags: swift, realm

I get filtered objects like:

```
realm.objects(Post.self).filter("title contains '\(searchText)'")
```

But I need case insensitive search option, Realm docs say:

> Case-insensitive comparisons for strings, such as name CONTAINS[c]
>   ‘Ja’. Note that only characters “A-Z” and “a-z” will be ignored for
>   case. Can be combined with the [d] modifier.

So how do I need do?

```
realm.objects(Post.self).filter("title contains[c] '\(searchText)'")
```

doesn't work...

**UPD:**

Got it. I was trying filter cyrillic symbols. So next question, where can I add cyrillic filtering?

Comment: how did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please use NSPredicate's interpolation rather than String interpolation:

```
realm.objects(Post.self).filter("title contains[c] %@", searchText)
```

Comment: "where can I add cyrillic filtering?" Try performing a query with both "case-insensitive" and "diacritic-insensitive" modifiers: `title contains[cd] %@`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: **Swift 5.1**

```
    realm.objects(Post.self).where { object in 
        object.title.contains(searchText.lowercased(), options: .caseInsensitive)
    }
```